# How to make Google Scholar profile private

Tags: google-scholar

How can I make my Google Scholar profile private after making it public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click the "Edit" link next to "My profile is public". Select the "My profile is private" option.](http://scholar.google.co.uk/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#setup)

Answer (score 1):

On the Google scholar page on the top right side of the page, click "my profile". This shows a pen/edit symbol next to your name. A box where you add your name, affiliations and other information is shown. In the same box at the end there is box next to "Make profile public". Check or uncheck it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is old. Next to your Name (which is next to your photo), there is a pen, click on it, at the bottom, unselect "make my profile public"